# android studio app crashes after starting foreground service

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple app that uses foreground service to make the app work on background with hello world message, but the issue is the app crashes when I click the button that start foreground service and suddenly the app closes.

any help will be appreciated, here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button startServiceButton = findViewById(R.id.startServiceButton);
    startServiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startForegroundService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, foregroundService.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

foregroundService.class:

```
public class foregroundServiceextends Service {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 123; // Unique ID for the notification
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "HelloWorldChannel"; // Notification channel ID

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification());

    // Perform any background tasks here
    // For this example, we'll simply display a message in the logs
    System.out.println("Hello, World! This is a background service.");

    return START_STICKY;
}

private Notification createNotification() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);

    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Hello, World Service")
            .setContentText("Running in the background")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.example.myapplicationtest">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".foregroundService" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: When asking for help with a crash, always post the stack trace.

Comment: ...and you can [use Logcat to obtain the stack trace](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html). Of note, you appear to be missing [the foreground service type](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an outdated code: Replace in your `foregroundService.class`

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

with

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
      0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

and add the following two lines after the above command:

```
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "your channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
getSystemService(NotificationManager.class).createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
```

That works for me.